# Split result by group on Twig

Tags: php, templates, twig, opencart

I'm trying to split my Opencart sells by user/region, but It's work is limited.

```
{% set handledPeople   = [] %}
{% set handledProducts = [] %}
{% for usuario in products if usuario.sellername not in handledPeople %}
        {% sellername: {{ usuario.sellername }} %}
        {% set handledPeople = handledPeople|merge([usuario.sellername]) %}
        {% for product in products if product.name == usuario.name and product not in handledProducts %}
            <p>{{ product.name }}</p>
            {% set handledProducts = handledProducts|merge([product.name]) %}            
        {% endfor %}/p>
{% endfor %}
```

Now, it's not showing all the products, It stop in the second one. Any ideas?

Comment: This process should be done in your controller and not inside `twig`

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?

This is not correct Twig syntax:

```
{% sellername: {{ usuario.sellername }} %}
```

Maybe you meant this:

```
{% set sellername = usuario.sellername %}
```

But it doesn't make sense anyway, because you don't use the variable `sellername` anywhere. If you remove that line of code and your array `products` looks like this:

```
"products" => array:4 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "sellername" => "John"
    "name" => "foo"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "sellername" => "John"
    "name" => "bar"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "sellername" => "Lisa"
    "name" => "baz"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "sellername" => "Daniel"
    "name" => "ham and spam"
  ]
]
```

You will get this:

```
        <p>foo</p>

/p>
        <p>baz</p>

/p>
        <p>ham and spam</p>

/p>
```

Maybe not what you wanted? :-)

If you instead do this:

```
{% set groupedProducts = {} %}
{% for product in products %}
    {% set groupedProducts = groupedProducts|merge({
        (product.sellername): groupedProducts[product.sellername]|default([])|merge([product.name])
    }) %}
{% endfor %}

{% for seller, products in groupedProducts %}
    {{ seller }} is selling:
    {% for product in products %}
        {{ product }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You will get this:

```
John is selling:
        foo
        bar
    Lisa is selling:
        baz
    Daniel is selling:
        ham and spam
```

Is this your desired result?

[See TwigFiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/ch331h)

PS. This kind of code (splitting results by group) would be better done in PHP instead of Twig (if possible; OpenCart can be messy).